# How Fake raid communicates with Operating system(Linux)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, storage, linux-device-driver, raid

I am a programmer, I studied about software, hardware and Fake raid's and I am unable to understand how fake raid communicates with operating system (Linux)? I mean which software layer or driver involved in this?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is Fake RAID?

Comment: @avd see http://skrypuch.com/raid/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fake RAID is created by motherboard by formatting disks and storing Fake RAID metadata on it.

There is a special tool by Red Hat - [`dmraid`](http://people.redhat.com/heinzm/sw/dmraid/readme)([source](http://people.redhat.com/heinzm/sw/dmraid/src/)). It's a some kind of bridge between Fake RAID and Linux device-mapper *dm-raid* target. Yes, it's confusing, don't mess `dmraid` and *dm-raid*. `dmraid` is utility, *dm-raid* is one of device-mapper targets.

`dmraid` tool scans all block devices and looks for Fake RAID metadata. After detecting Fake RAIDs it create corresponding device-mapper devices. For example, if there was Fake RAID0 then `dmraid` will create mapped device with striped target ([dm-stripe.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/dm-stripe.c?v=3.12)). If there was Fake RAID1, then it will create mapped device with raid target ([dm-raid.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/md/dm-raid.c?v=3.12)).

So, the answer is: Fake RAID communicates with Linux through device-mapper. There are several drivers involved in this (dm-stripe, dm-raid) and useful utility dmraid.